# How could I delete Google Chrome User Data files by prompt command?

Tags: windows, command-line, google-chrome, batch-file

Would like to delete this folder and file:

```
DEL %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\"User Data"\Default*.* /F /S
DEL %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\"User Data"\First
```

Trying to execute in a batch file they don't work as expected. (Default folder still there after running).

Anything is wrong?

These files are from Google Chrome, so it's a just way to reset the browser by command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The `Default` folder is still there after running the batch file

```
DEL %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\"User Data"\Default*.* /F /S
```

You are missing a `\` after `Default`.

The following command should work:

```
DEL %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\"User Data"\Default\*.* /F /S
```

---

#### But I don't want to be prompted

Add `/Q` to set "Quiet mode, do not give a Yes/No Prompt before deleting."

```
DEL %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\"User Data"\Default\*.* /F /S /Q
```

---

#### But I want to remove the directories as well.

Use `rd` to remove the directories

```
RD %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\"User Data"\Default /s /q
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [del](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) - Delete one or more files.
- [rd](http://ss64.com/nt/rd.html) - Delete folder(s).

Comment: Most of the settings are saved in `Preferences` file in that `default` directory.

Comment: @Biswa So? The OP said "it's a just way to reset the browser by command prompt". Resetting the browser is a lot more than just preferences.

Comment: So alternatively, to reset user data, one may delete only the `Preferences` file, no need to remove whole `default` folder :)

Comment: @Biswa The OP wants to completely reset the browser. That folder also contains the cache, extension, extension settings, session storage, cookies, history etc ... which are all user data.